# Methods for 3D histograms comparison

Tags: histogram

When I wish to compare 2D image histograms I can use methods like Chi-Square and Intersection but what are my options if I wish to compare 3D histograms (e.g, based on R,G,B values)?

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what a "3D histogram" is.  If you have a three-band ("RGB") image it will yield three *ordinary* histograms, one for each band.  That doesn't even sound 2D, much less 3D!

Comment: this is a scatter version of what I mean http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/plugins/color-inspector.html

Comment: Thank you: that really is 3D! It is a histogram in which the vectors $(r,g,b)$ have been binned and counted. Since chi-squared statistics apply just as well to such objects as the usual histograms, and you seem to be seeking alternatives, I would guess you have some particular kinds of comparisons in mind. What are they?  What are you trying to find out when you compare two such image histograms?

Comment: Both methods you mention for 2D should apply to 3D. Are you seeking further methods than those?

Comment: Yes, I am seeking further methods.